# Getting time difference in micro or milli seconds in php

Tags: php, timestamp

I am trying to find time required to execute some function using php.
I want accuracy of milli or micro seconds but i get difference in seconds.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php

$time_start = microtime(true);


usleep(2000000);

$time_end = microtime(true);

$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did nothing in $time micro seconds\n";


?>
```

The output i get is 2 micro seconds but it should be 2000000 micro seconds according to program.

If i keep usleep(100) it will give me 0 difference.

Please help me with some solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `microsecond(true)` is a float, "which represents the current time in seconds" and "accurate to the nearest microsecond" (http://php.net/microtime). Meaning decimals before the comma are in seconds and the decimals after the comma represent the microseconds.

Therefore the example in the manual is more correct than your variant:

```
echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
```

If the execution takes exactly two seconds, it will output:

```
Did nothing in 2 seconds
```

If the execution takes two seconds and 500 milliseconds, it will output:

```
Did nothing in 2.5 seconds
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
<?php

function secondsConverter($dateTime1,$dateTime2)
{
    $hour=abs($dateTime1['hour']-$dateTime2['hour'])*3600;
    $minutes=abs($dateTime1['minute']-$dateTime2['minute'])*60;
    $seconds=abs($dateTime1['second']-$dateTime2['second']);

   return $hour+$minutes+$seconds;
}

$dateTime1=date_parse("10:00:00.5");
$dateTime2=date_parse("11:00:00.5");
echo secondsConverter($dateTime1,$dateTime2);

?>
```